# Alternative way to remove object from an array of json objects other than splice

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am still fairly new to JavaScript and I need help with an issue I am having.

I have a Java function that returns an array of json objects as such:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "phone": "1234567890",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "contact": {
      "personal": "test test",
      "professional": "professionaltest test"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have various scenarios in my API test where I am sending a POST request but purposefully missing some of the key/value pairs in the json. Such as:

1. Send the request by skipping contact.
2. Send the request by skipping phone.
3. etc.

I have researched and it seems that using .splice can be used to remove an object. However, from what I understand, the removal criteria is primarily driven by indexes (indices?). I'd rather not use remove by index in case something changes the output of the function in the future. Is there a way to remove by key name? Any alternative methods would be greatly appreciated too.

Comment: Are you looking for [the delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) ?

Comment: You can use `.findIndex()` to find the index by key name, then call `splice()`.

Comment: What you showed is not an array of objects, it's just a single object containing nested objects.

Comment: You remove from objects by key: `delete obj.payload.contact;`

Comment: Your example missing an array? Which one is `array of` that you talking about in question?

Comment: You mean remove properties from objects? Not objects from the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite way to remove an value from an object.
For example, you want to remove phone from the payload object.

```
  var { payload } = // your object
  var { phone, ...newValue } = payload
  console.log(newValue)
```

newValue is an copy of payload object without the phone key value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeByKeys(obj, keys) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      return newObj;
    }
    return { ...newObj, [key]: obj[key] };
  }, {});
}

const person = { name: 'bob', age: 36 };

removeByKeys(person, ['age']); // { name: 'bob' }
```

The has the same API as lodash omit. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit. You can use that if you have more complicated use-cases, but the above is simple enough.